# Get Visitor IP address is not working using PHP

Tags: php

I an trying to get visitor ip address to my WordPress site . to do this I write a function `getcustomerip()` but it showing nothing . can someone help me to what I am doing wrong.

```
function getcustomerip(){

    // Get real visitor IP behind CloudFlare network
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
              $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
              $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
    }
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
        $ip = $client;
    }elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
        $ip = $forward;
    }else{
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `@`s. Do you have errors? What is `$ip` returned as?

Comment: its return `::1` or null

Comment: Which `if` are you entering? I assume you are using cloudflare?

Comment: yes my site is in cloudflare ..